# MySQLi+PHP: количество и проверка наличия по свойствам 1 запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица:
`id(num), name(text), fld1(num), fld2(num), fld3(num)`
При этом, выборка ведётся по указанным свойствам, например

```
SELECT id FROM $db_table WHERE fld1 LIKE '1' AND fld2 LIKE '4'.
```

Есть задача:

1. Вывести счётчик общего кол-ва подпадающих под условие записей БД
2. Если по выбору варианта, в БД нет ничего - подменить элемент.

В общем, это мой наверное, 20-й запрос в SQL - и я-таки не слишком понимаю как его сгенерить, а потом - разобрать, а сроки - до понедельника %)

Comment: @cyadvert 20 запрос, а не вопрос

Comment: а :) ну да... виноват :)

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет:

```
SELECT Count(id) FROM $db_table WHERE fld1 = '1' AND fld2 = '4'
```